# how to find minimum and maximum value in object literal by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to get minimum value from object literal and want to use it in anuglarjs i.e., :-

```
scope.data = {
    'studentName' : "Anand", 
    'socialStudies' : "98",
    'english' : "90",
    'math' : "80"
};
```

Initially it will be single object but after adding more data it will be just like array data. So I want to find out each row minimum and maximum value.

I have already try below code for min and max but didn't get the solution as its giving me "**NaN**".

```
var maxVal = Math.max.apply(Math,scope.data);
```

Please suggest some good option. I am using it in angularjs.
Waiting for your response.

My entire piece of code is as under :-

```
scope.save = function (item){
        scope.person = {
            'name' : scope.person.name, 
            'hindi' : scope.person.hindi,
            'english' : scope.person.english,
            'math' : scope.person.math
        };

        if(typeof rootScope.students === 'undefined'){
            rootScope.students = [];
            rootScope.students.push(scope.person);
        }else{
            rootScope.students.push(scope.person);
        }
        location.path("/");
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are tyring to do.  max, min of what?  Are you looking for the min and max numeric value of any property on a single object?  Or do you have an array of objects and you want the max and min value of a particular property from each object in the array?  Also, what about non-numeric properties?

Comment: What in you example is the 'max', `98` or `Anand`?!

Comment: @A.Wolff: `Anand` is obviously the longest string :-)

Comment: Yes @jfriend00 I have a form of HTML. I want to save data whenever user will add new record. I am looking for min and max numeric value of each property of scope.data object.

please suggest!!

Comment: What do you mean, it is "just like array data"? Why don't you use an actual array (then your code would work)?

Comment: So here is my entire piece of code, I am creating a array and passing new object whenever user will add data. Hope its clear now :-


    scope.save = function (item){
   scope.person = {
    'name' : scope.person.name, 
    'hindi' : scope.person.hindi,
    'english' : scope.person.english,
    'math' : scope.person.math
   };
   
   if(typeof rootScope.students === 'undefined'){
    rootScope.students = [];
    rootScope.students.push(scope.person);
   }else{
    rootScope.students.push(scope.person);
   }
   location.path("/");
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it that checks only numeric looking properties and returns both the max and min values and their corresponding property names (since I assume that would be useful to know):

```
scope.data = {
    'studentName' : "Anand", 
    'socialStudies' : "98",
    'english' : "90",
    'math' : "80"
};

function findMaxMin(obj) {
    var max = Number.MIN_VALUE, min = Number.MAX_VALUE, val;
    var maxProp, minProp;
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            val = +obj[prop];
            if (!isNaN(val)) {
                if (val > max) {
                    maxProp = prop;
                    max = val;
                }
                if (val < min) {
                    minProp = prop;
                    min = val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // if no numeric looking properties, then return null
    if (!maxProp) {
        return null;
    }
    return {minVal: min, minProp: minProp, maxVal: max, maxProp: maxProp};
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/q81g6ehb/

---

And, if you want to use this on an array, you can just call it for each array element:

```
function findMaxMinArray(arr) {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var m = findMaxMin(arr[i]);
        m.obj = arr[i];
        results.push(m);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/uv50y3e8/

---

If you wanted it to auto-detect whether an array was past in or not and just always return an array of results, you could do this:

```
function findMaxMinAny(obj) {
    var results = [];
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var m = findMaxMin(arr[i]);
            m.obj = arr[i];
            results.push(m);
        }
    } else {
        // only a single object
        results.push(findMaxMin(obj));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, its working fine in jsfiddle. Will check and update it in my code.

Comment: Need small favor also, its not working in the case of multiple object. If there will be mutiple data so its return null.

scope.data = [{
    'studentName' : "Anand", 
    'socialStudies' : "98",
    'english' : "90",
    'math' : "80"
},{
    'studentName' : "deepak", 
    'socialStudies' : "98",
    'english' : "90",
    'math' : "80"
}];

Comment: @Ananddeepsingh - you did not specify that in your question.  I can adapt my answer in a moment.  In the future, please show examples of all the types of data you want it to work with in your question.  Do you want a single max min for the entire array?  Or do you want an array of max/min, one for each student?

Comment: @Ananddeepsingh - and in the result, do you only need the max/min values or do you also need to know the subject and the student that the max or min value goes with?

Comment: I am apologies for ambiguity. I will need min and max for each and every student. Lets say there is 3 student so I want to know student no 1 having min marks 80 and Max marks 90, student no 2 is having min marks 56 and Max marks 80 and student no 3 is having min marks 34 and max marks is 45.

Comment: @Ananddeepsingh - more options added to my answer.

Comment: @Ananddeepsingh - since it looks like you may be fairly new at StackOverflow, are you aware that if you get your question answered, you can select one of the answers as the "best answer" by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer.  Besides indicating to the community that your question is now answered and which answered provided the most help, this will also earn you some reputation points here on StackOverflow for following the right process.

Comment: yeah I know it but I need 15 reputation point to vote for best answer. I already tried it but not able to vote as of now.

Comment: @Ananddeepsingh - you need 15 to upvote, but not to "accept" with the green checkmark.  You can always accept an answer to a question you asked.  Instructions [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/164634).

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.map()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to translate items into new array, if the callback returns null or undefined that item will not be included. You can use that to filter the result ( for example, to remove the non numeric values ).

```
var data = {
    'studentName' : "Anand", 
    'socialStudies' : "98",
    'english' : "90",
    'math' : "80"
};

var array = $.map( data, function( val ) { 
    return $.isNumeric( val ) ? val : null; 
});

console.log( Math.max.apply( null, array ) ); // 98
```

Comment: thanks @danijel for your snippet but its giving me array as "-Infinity"