# How to get the property with the largest number?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I need to return a new object from an original object. 
The original object's property values are numbers bigger than 0, and I want to return the property with the largest value. 
Edit: I want to return the largest property only if the property's $.isNumeric() is true; Apologies for my poor English.

```
obj = {2:1, 3:4, a:8, 5:2, 4:5 }; //expected newobj = {5:5};
```

Comment: A related answer: [how to find minimum and maximum value in object literal by javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143302/how-to-find-minimum-and-maximum-value-in-object-literal-by-javascript/30143429#30143429)

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, but for starters you can't have an object literal with duplicate keys. You have three properties with 3 as the property name.

Comment: True, I will edit it.

Comment: Why would the result not be `{a:8}` as that is the largest numeric value?  Unclear question as it is written.  Largest property?  Largest value?  Which needs to be numeric?

Comment: The largest property is `5`, not `4`. The largest value is `8`, not `5`. And neither `5` nor `8` should be skipped because `$.isNumeric` returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Largest number in an array of strings (ignoring non-numeric):

```js
function maxInArr(arr) {
    return Math.max.apply(void 0, arr.filter($.isNumeric).map(Number));
}
```

Largest property:

```js
var maxProp = maxInArr(Object.keys(obj));
```

Largest value:

```js
var maxVal = maxInArr(Object.keys(obj).map(function(p){
    return obj[p];
}));
```

Build the object:

```js
var obj2 = {};
obj2[maxProp] = maxVal;
obj2; // {5: 8}
```

Comment: Isn't this getting the highest property name, not the highest property value?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, and OP says "largest property with largest value". So I think this answers the question, even if the expected result in the question is incoherent.

Comment: Confusing question for sure, but the result they show of `{3:5}` is not the largest key.

Comment: Due to the confusion of question, I reedit it little bit.  Sorry and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood question correctly this should be possible answer.

```
var obj = {2:1, 3:4, a:8, 5:2, 3:5, 3:5};
var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
for(var propertyName in obj) {
    if(!isNaN(propertyName) && propertyName > 0){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && obj[propertyName] > max){
            max = obj[propertyName];
        }
    }
}

console.log(max);
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bLe9jbj/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your array into this simple function:

```
function heighest(yourArray) {
    var keys = Object.keys(yourArray);
    var values = Object.keys(yourArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
    {
        keys[i] = parseInt(keys[i]);
        values[i] = parseInt(values[i]);
    }
    var highestKey = Math.max.apply(Math, keys);
    alert('Heighest key: ' + highestKey + ', with value ' + yourArray[highestKey]);
};
```